# WPF DataGrid AutoGeneratingColumn event returns -1 for all ColumnDisplayIndex

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

The following code returns -1 for each displayed column.

Anyone knows the answer? I tried to use ColumnDisplayIndexChanged event. But it did not show anything.

i.konuk

```
private void dg_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
        {
            string headername = e.Column.Header.ToString();

            //Cancel the column you don't want to generate
            if (headername == "Occupation")
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }

            //update column details when generating
            if (headername == "FirstName")
            {
                e.Column.Header = "First Name";
            }

            //update column details when generating
            if (headername == "LastName")
            {
                e.Column.Header = "Last Name";
            }

            int myin = e.Column.DisplayIndex;

            System.Text.StringBuilder messageBoxCS = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            messageBoxCS.AppendFormat("{0} = {1}", "Column", myin);
            messageBoxCS.AppendLine();
            MessageBox.Show(messageBoxCS.ToString(), "DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEvent");

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AutoGeneratingColumn`  event occurs when an individual column is auto-generated in other words the event is called when columns are forming in the dataGrid. This means no columns are displayed yet.

`DataGridColumn.DisplayIndex` property displays the position of the column in the DataGrid. We have not yet displayed the columns in AutoGeneratingColumn  event. The DisplayIndex property has a default value of -1 before it is added to the DataGrid.Columns collection.
Thats why you are getting the default value of -1.

`ColumnDisplayIndexChanged` Event is called when you have selected a particular column and changed the dispayed order in the `DataGrid`.

Hope I have answered your Question!

Comment: Satish; Thank you very much for the clear explanation. i. konuk

Comment: @I.Konuk Glad I was able to help you !!